# XSLT value-of returns actual values instead of nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSL Transforms and trying to learn, but I'm stuck on an issue right now.  I am receiving information back from an API that has either has a "parent" node or not.

```
<nodeList>
    <nodeInfo>
        <nodeName />
        <nodeAddress />
        <nodeEtc />
    </nodeInfo>
    <nodeInfo>
        <nodeName />
        <nodeAddress />
        <nodeEtc />
    </nodeInfo>
    <nodeInfo>
        <nodeName />
        <nodeAddress />
        <nodeEtc />
    </nodeInfo>
</nodeList>
```

or

```
<nodeInfo>
    <nodeName />
    <nodeAddress />
    <nodeEtc />
</nodeInfo>
```

and I am trying to get the XSLT to create a variable based on the single or multiples, but wrap the single in  because I need to count the nodes later.  Here is my XSLT

```
<xsl:variable name="listOfData">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/nodeList">
            <xsl:value-of select="/nodeList" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <nodeList>
                <xsl:value-of select="/nodeInfo" />
            </nodeList>
        <xsl:otherwise
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

When I do it this way, the multiples work fine, but the single turns out to have a node of  with every child node as the value of the  just preceded by \n  new lines.  Any help would be greatly appreciated and if any further explanation links could be provided to get a better understanding.  Thanks!

Comment: What version of XSLT? Please, provide a minimal and complete example with input, stylesheet and output.

Comment: `xsl:value-of` simply creates a text node with the string value of the selected nodes (XSLT 2 and 3) or the string value of the first selected node (XSLT 1), it never selects or copies the selected node(s). So you either want to use `xsl:sequence` instead (in XSLT 2 or 3) to simply select the nodes or `xsl:copy-of` (in XSLT 1) to copy them.